# Is there a way to introduce Swagger automated documentation into a solution that uses Flask Bluperints?

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I would like to introduce Swagger documentation to a project I built using Flask and Blueprints, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

e.g.

```py
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

class HealthController():
   def __init__(self):
      self.blueprint = self.define_routes()

   def define_routes(self):
      blueprint = Blueprint('health', __name__)
      @blueprint.route('/api/health', methods=['GET'])
      def health():
         return flask.jsonify({"result": True}), 200
      return blueprint

application = Flask(__name__)
application.register_blueprint(HealthController().blueprint)
application.run()
```

How do I introduce a `flasgger` or any other framework generating Swagger UI while sticking to Flask and Blueprints?

I've tried using flask-openapi3, flassger and searching around but so far, I could not find the solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [apiflask](https://apiflask.com/openapi/) works perfectly well with the blueprints.
All you have to do is to follow the manual and replace `Blueprint` class from Flask with `APIBlueprint` from apiflask.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).